# How to avoid error while running mobile tests: Original error: socket hang up

Tags: java, android, appium

I have android tests which are running through jenkins on appium docker image, but everytime causes this error:

```
Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
```

What i tried:

1. Updated all binaries and appium version
2. Implemented dynamic port change
3. Implemented listener to quit/close app

Don't know what causes it and what to do.

Comment: Did you tried with disabling and enabling the debugging mode on test device and also kill & restart your appium server?

Comment: Yes, it didn't helped

Comment: Can you please share the github link to your script so that the issue can be debugged & identified for resolution?

Comment: same issue here. Just put the basic settings through a file and tried to start a super simple test, same error.

Answer (score 1):

i got this issue when using
Appium-Server-GUI-windows-1.22.3-4,
and the appium-server-non-gui-1.23 has the same issue
with android 11 real device,
python3.11, Appium-python-Client version 2.7.1.
So i change to Appium-Server-windows-1.21.0-GUI, and it works ok.

Comment: one more, after an unnormal exception test completed, such as your android application crashed, or appium driver error； remember restart the android real device to kill the session (driver.quit()) and socket using on devices before